# Conditions for equivalences of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove: $$ \bigcup \left \{ P(X)|X\in A \right \} = P(\bigcup A) \Leftrightarrow \exists x\in A(\forall y\in A( y\subseteq x))$$
I know how to go from the right side to the left.  I need help with the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\cup A\in\wp(\cup A)$ so that based on the LHS we are allowed to conclude:$$\cup A\in \cup\{\wp(x)\mid x\in A\}$$

That means that $\cup A\in\wp(x)$ or equivalently $\cup A\subseteq x$ for some $x\in A$.

Then for every $y\in A$ we find $y\subseteq\cup A\subseteq x$.